# How do I use multiple arguments from an array to construct an execl() call in C?

Tags: c, arrays, exec

I have a string array in C named `args[]` - now how can I use this list of arguments to construct a proper call to `execl()`?

So if the array contains:

```
{"/bin/ls","ls","-a","-l"}
```

...how can I eventually construct an `execl()` call that is:

```
execl("/bin/ls","ls","-a","-l",NULL);
```

I must be thinking about this wrong, as I can't find anything online, just talk about defining functions that can take a variable number of arguments.

Comment: I was about to ask this question and found this one :) Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken directly from "man execl"

> The execv() and execvp() functions provide  an  array  of  pointers  to
>          null-terminated  strings  that represent the argument list available to
>          the new program.  The first argument, by convention,  should  point  to
>          the  filename  associated  with  the file being executed.  The array of
>          pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

EDIT:
Here are the prototypes.

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

Comment: That's what I get for having tunnel vision and just "using what I know".  Thanks to both answers.

Answer (score 8):

If you have an array that you want to pass to one of [the `exec*` family](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/execl.3.asp), you should use `execv` rather than `execl`.

Your array should be terminated by a NULL pointer, which yours currently isn't:

```
{"/bin/ls","ls","-a","-l", NULL}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure your args[] array has a NULL pointer as the last element, then call

`execv(args[0], &args[1]);`